# unable to launch pr2 keyboard teleop on hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, pr2, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to launch pr2 keyboard teleop on hydro but I shown the following error

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_teleop/teleop_pr2_keyboard]: can't locate node [teleop_pr2_keyboard] in package [pr2_teleop]

Did anyone faced the same issue before?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201815/unable-to-launch-pr2-keyboard-teleop-on-hydro/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sort of question has been asked and answered many times. There are a few basic possibilities:

- You've installed pr2_teleop from source, and it hasn't been built
- You've installed pr2_teleop from debs, and there's a bug in the install command.

In this case, it looks like the second option is the case. I've reported this as a bug: https://github.com/PR2/pr2_apps/issues/14

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @ahendrix and @zenifed for pointing this out. I've updated the repository and re-released the package. These changes will be reflected in 0.5.15 and can be used immediately by cloning the repo.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1